# flask-admin: How to make columns read-only according to other columns' value?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I've built a system that allows users to apply for code review and wait for manager to approve.

And now what I want to achieve is as below:

1. If it's **approved**, 
   [image]
   then all the fields become **read-only**(I manually set **Project name** as read-only here):

[image]

2. If it's **rejected**,

   [image]

   then all the fields become **editable**. Of course, when creating a new project, all the fields should be editable.
   [image]

   The code of class `Project` and `ProjectView` are as below:

   ```
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
    from flask_security import current_user

    # Create Flask application
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    class Project(db.Model):

           id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
           project_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))
           version = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))
           SVN = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)
           approve = db.Column(db.Boolean())

           def __unicode__(self):
               return self.name

    class ProjectView(sqla.ModelView):
        def is_accessible(self):
            if not current_user.is_active or not current_user.is_authenticated:
                return False
            return False

        @property
        def _form_edit_rules(self):
            return rules.RuleSet(self, self.form_rules)

        @_form_edit_rules.setter
        def _form_edit_rules(self, value):
            pass

        @property
        def _form_create_rules(self):
            return rules.RuleSet(self, self.form_rules)

        @_form_create_rules.setter
        def _form_create_rules(self, value):
            pass

        @property
        def form_rules(self):
        form_rules = [
            rules.Field('project_name'),
            rules.Field('version'),
            rules.Field('SVN'),
        ]
        if not has_app_context() or current_user.has_role('superuser'):
            form_rules.append('approve')
   ```

   In my opinion, since **approve** is a **boolean** variable, there should be a 
   condition judgement to tell if it is 0 or 1 and then the field become read-only  or editable accordingly.

   Thanks for any advise in advance.

Comment: I don't know this library, but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874846/readonly-text-field-in-flask-admin-modelview) could be a solution

Comment: Yes, I checked link you provided, but what I want is set the columns read-only dynamically, instead of fixed to read-only all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already noticed setting `readonly` property for a field is [rather simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23959450/6682517) but making it dynamic is a bit tricky.

First of all you need a custom field class:

```
from wtforms.fields import StringField

class ReadOnlyStringField(StringField):
    @staticmethod
    def readonly_condition():
        # Dummy readonly condition
        return False

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Adding `readonly` property to `input` field
        if self.readonly_condition():
            kwargs.setdefault('readonly', True)
        return super(ReadOnlyStringField, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    def populate_obj(self, obj, name):
        # Preventing application from updating field value
        # (user can modify web page and update the field)
        if not self.readonly_condition():
            super(ReadOnlyStringField, self).populate_obj(obj, name)
```

Set [form_overrides](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_overrides) attribute for your view:

```
class ProjectView(sqla.ModelView):
    form_overrides = {
        'project_name': ReadOnlyStringField
    }
```

You need to pass custom `readonly_condition` function to `ReadOnlyStringField` instance. The easiest way I found is overriding [edit_form](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.edit_form) method:

```
class ProjectView(sqla.ModelView):
    def edit_form(self, obj=None):
        def readonly_condition():
            if obj is None:
                return False
            return obj.approve
        form = super(ProjectView, self).edit_form(obj)
        form.project_name.readonly_condition = readonly_condition
        return form
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Good day! I followed your 1st and 2nd parts: `class ReadOnlyStringField` and `form_overrides`; however, the `project name` does not become read-only.

Comment: @Samoth Greetings! Without 3rd part `readonly` status will be statically based on dummy `readonly_condition` method which always return `False`. You can change it to `True` to check it actually sets `readonly` status. I just thought the field should be readable by default :)

Comment: thanks but I set both `readonly_condition` to be `True` and `False`, he `project nam`e does not become read-only.

Comment: @Samoth Could you post updated code? Maybe github is really more suitable.

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin, Yes, I've been trying to put my code on github these days but in vain.  Ii seems I have to use command line to commit code and cannot upload directly.

Comment: OK, it is done and please visit the link, I finally put it under my R programming repo: https://github.com/samoth21/ProgrammingAssignment2/tree/master/auth

Comment: @Samoth Great! But at the moment application uses Philip Martin solution which doesn't work unfortunately (see my comment under his post).

Comment: Martin's solution does not work for me, the fields are not dynamically become read-only based o the value of `approve`.

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin, kindly let me know if the application can be run on your machine since in my time zone it's time to take a rest now,  haha.

Comment: @Samoth I think it will be better to switch application to my solution. I can then make code review and find possible problems why it is not working in your case :) Nice resting!

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin, Yes sure I am willing to do that, but actually I am not quite sure how to integrate your third part (`class ProjectView(sqla.ModelView)`) with my application.

Comment: I already added your 1st part in my application( `class ReadOnlyStringField(StringField)`) , and per my understanding the 2nd part  s just for a demo, so I did not add them.

Comment: @Samoth Just add `edit_form` method to your `ProjectView` (`SWProjectView`), it should not conflict with other code. Without it `readonly` condition will not by dynamic.

Comment: @ Sergey Shubi, I am not sure I understand correctly what you just suggested. I wrote another class`ProjectView` to inherit  `SWProjectView` and then add `edit form` in it.  And I add the view using `admin.add_view(ProjectView(Project, db.session))`. Though it still not work.

Comment: @Samoth No, add `edit_form` method and `form_overrides` attribute to `SWProjectView` just as they are posted in my example.

Comment: @ Sergey Shub, the solution works well and will be accepted as the best answer. By the way, I've been trying to change the **save** button on the edit and create form to other string something like **confrim** or **submit** but could not find the file to edit, would you please advise?

Comment: @Samoth Thanks, you are welcome! Button text can't be easily changed, you need to override several macros and blocks in your "edit.html" and "create.html" templates to change [render_form_buttons](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/templates/bootstrap3/admin/lib.html#L146) macro. You may want to create new question. I haven't found similar questions on SO — it can be useful for community.

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin: If the field is a selectable drop down button, it seems cannot become read-only? Thanks.

Comment: @Samoth Not found a way to make it, sorry. `QuerySelectField` which is used in dropdowns cannot be subclassed due to some flask-admin bug.

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin: I think there is a big defect in my application: every users  can see all the project list. Is it possible to restrict the user can only can see his/her own project? Since flask-admin examples provided are all **role** based until last weekend I suddenly noticed the defect. Thanks so much for any advise in advance.

Comment: @Samoth Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26351005/6682517) - you will need to override `get_query` and `get_count_query` methods in your `ProjectView`. I already tried this solution in my project and it worked.

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin: Thanks, and what is the variable I need to replace `paid` in my application? Would you please explain more because I am not so sure what is the variable here to restrict the user can only can see his/her own project.

Comment: @Samoth You need to pass SQLAlchemy filter. In your case return value may look like this `self.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.reviewers.user_id == current_user.id)`. Not sure how it will work: your `User.projects` relationship is commented and don't know if `current_user.id` is your actual user ID.

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin: Thanks, so it looks like I should make a relationship between `class project` and `class user` since you mentioned `User.projects`..

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin: There's one more question on the answer. If I set the field as `ReadOnlyStringField`, then the filed's height become fixed(one liner) and cannot be extended; this is not comfortable when user is editing it. Thanks.

Comment: @Samoth Hi! It's quite easily fixed: declare `ReadOnlyTextAreaField(TextAreaField)` the same way as `ReadOnlyStringField` and use it for multi-line input.

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin: Excuse me I've been stuck with an issue and cannot resolve it, would you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908969/flask-admin-sqlalchemy-exc-interfaceerrorerror-binding-parameter-8), whether I use `__str__` and `__repr__` both not worked. The query worked and returned user names correctly but the data type is still an memory location thus cannot be store in database.

Comment: @Samoth Hi! It looks like your last issue doesn't refer to your last question. This error is mentioned in `wtforms` questions, try to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888698/sqlalchemy-exc-interfaceerror-unprintable-interfaceerror-object).

Comment: @ Sergey Shubin:  Yes I saw this post before but the situation seems different. I define many-to-many relationship between **role&user** and **team &user**. And it works fine. But when I try to query it(by user's id and teams), the error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer I put on here had a major flaw. The following uses a different approach by analyzing the form itself and adding `readonly: True` to `render_kw` for a particular form if a certain condition is met.

```
class ProjectView(sqla.ModelView):
    # ... other class code

    def edit_form(self, obj=None):
        # grab form from super
        form = super(ProjectView, self).edit_form(obj)

        # form.approved.data should be the same as approved
        # if approved is included in the form
        if form.approved.data:
            if form.project_name.render_kw:
                form.project_name.render_kw.update({
                    'readonly': True
                })
            else:
                form.project_name.render_kw = {'readonly': True}
        return form
```

This is a bit hacky, and it requires that `approved` be in the edit form. If you used this solution, you could either add `approved` as a `readonly` field or, instead of `readonly`, you could remove the `approved` field from the form in the above class method.

Comment: thanks and I revised my code as follow: `def _form_edit_rules(self):
        return {
             CustomizableField('project_name', field_args={
                 'readonly': not self.model.approve
             }),
             rules.RuleSet(self, self.edit_form_rules)
         }`                                                                                                                but the error occurs: `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'visible_fields'`

Comment: I found 2 situations:  `not self.model.approve`: then the fields are editable all the time; and `self.model.approve`: then the fields are read-only all the time. It's not dynamically based on the `approve` value.

Comment: Also didn't work unfortunately: `self.model.approve` is model _class_ attribute not _instance_ attribute so it always typecasts to `True`.

Comment: @SergeyShubin, thanks for pointing that out. That was an oversight on my part. I changed my answer to edit the form directly based on the content of the form.

Answer (score 2):

For me this trick was the simplest way to do it:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_admin.form.rules import Field


class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    not_editable = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))
    editable = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))


class ReadonlyFiledRule(Field):
    def __call__(self, form, form_opts=None, field_args={}):
        field_args['readonly'] = True
        return super(ReadonlyFiledRule, self).__call__(form, form_opts, field_args)


class ExampleView(ModelView):
    form_edit_rules = (ReadonlyFiledRule('not_editable'), 'editable', )
```

**Update (the easiest way):**

```
class ExampleView(ModelView):
    form_widget_args = {
        'not_editable': {
            'readonly': True
        }
    }
```